# Há dígrafos em "arte"?

Tags: fonética

Na palavra *arte*, é pronunciada a letra *R* e a letra *E*? Podemos dizer que há dois dígrafos nessa palavra e que as letras *R* e *E* são letras diacríticas?

Comment: ar e te não são dígrafos.

Comment: Poderia até se dizer que *te* é dígrafo de /tch/.

Comment: Mas há dois fonemas na primeira sílaba "ar"? Não consigo os identificar.

Comment: @sidney, se tiver um sotaque caipira, talvez diga [átch]. No português padrão brasileiro, a primeira sílaba são dois fonemas: /a/ e /r/. O grafema <a> representa /a/ e o grafema <r> representa /r/. O som de /a/ geralmente é uma [vogal anterior aberta não arredondada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogal_anterior_aberta_n%C3%A3o_arredondada) — não se assuste! E o som de /r/ varia, mas geralmente ou é um som de cachorro bravo «RRRRRR» ou um som de doente, como o h em «ahá!». Se não tiver entendido ou tiver outra dúvida, está bem-vindo a perguntar!

Comment: Começo a compreender. Estou revisando esses conceitos agora, provavelmente entenderei melhor quando avançar um pouco mais. Obrigadíssimo.

Comment: @Schilive, não está correto, dígrafo é algo 100% escrito!

Comment: @ErgativeMan, não conseguir entendê-lo Você poderia explicar?

Comment: A variação de <te> pra só para o fone [t͡ʃ], alofone de /t/, é específica, e muitas vezes é a consoante e a vogal palatal, portanto só um caso de alofonia, mas entendo a sua posição, mas peço desculpas, achei que você tinha dito que /te/ era dígrafo do som, respondi tarde da noite e confundi! Então sim, em certos dialetos faz sentido Hahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, não há dígrafos na palavra "arte". Um dígrafo é um conjunto de duas letras que representam um único som, como "ch" em "chuva" ou "nh" em "ganhar". Na palavra "arte", cada letra é pronunciada individualmente. Portanto, não há dígrafos nessa palavra.

Além disso, as letras R e E em "arte" não são consideradas letras diacríticas. As letras diacríticas são aquelas usadas para modificar o som ou a forma de outras letras na mesma palavra, como o acento agudo em "café" ou o til em "maçã". As letras R e E em "arte" são simplesmente letras que compõem a palavra.